# NLP - subject of sentence

Tags: text, nlp, text-mining, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I am trying to get the main subject of a sentence, i.e what a sentence is talking about (not the grammatical subject which may be different).

So far I have got

1.) OpenNLP in Java which is giving me sentence detection, POS tagging, parsing, tokenizer and Name Finder.

2.) MatlParser,stanford Parser - which can give the grammatical subject of a simple sentence by dependency parsing.

I think a noun or a noun phrase will always be subject in more general sense,but a sentence can have many nouns and noun phrases.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

As you correctly pointed out, syntax is not sufficient. One would have to use some form of shallow semantic analysis to identify what you call the "subject". I believe it is more often referred to as Agent in the context of SRL (Semantic Role Labeling). There are open source tools (e.g. [UIUC SRL parser](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/demo/srl/)) to perform semantic role labeling, at least for English, but they usually work on separate predicates, of which in a sentence there may be several, so one has to somehow figure out which "subject" is the "main" one.

I do not think that the latter notion is well defined, in fact, as in a complex sentence it might not be clear which subject is the "main" one. It might make more sense for a particular kind of sentences, but not in general. I think it would help if you described the data you're working with and/or gave some examples.

P.S. you might consider asking this on https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/